# Find top frequency word in string and check if string only contains [a-z][A-Z] characters

Tags: python, list, python-3.9

I have created some code in Python to find the top frequency word in a string. I am pretty new in Python and ask for your help to see if I could code this better and more effectively.
(code returns one integer with highest frequency word in the string.)
Also I want to make sure that string only contains [a-z][A-Z] , I tried it but don't know how to do that check.

```
from collections import Counter

class WordCounter:
   def __init__(self, word, frequency):
      self.word = word
      self.frequency = frequency

# find_top_frequency should return the highest frequency in the text
def find_top_frequency(text: str) -> int:
    incoming_string = text.split()
    incoming_string= [x.lower() for x in incoming_string]
    Words_in_dict_count = {}
    for i in incoming_string:
        if i not in Words_in_dict_count.keys():
            Words_in_dict_count[i] = 0
        Words_in_dict_count[i] = Words_in_dict_count[i] + 1
    return (max(Words_in_dict_count.values()))
```

print("\nTop frequency of same word in string is: " +str(WordCounter.find_top_frequency("I would love to make this code better but hope you can help me with it. Thank you helping me out. Hope you can help me."))+"\n")

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.isalpha()` to filter for words that only have letters in them, and use `Counter.most_common` to get the most common word.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def find_top_frequency(text: str) -> int:
...     return Counter(
...         word for word in text.split() if word.isalpha()
...     ).most_common(1).pop()[1]
...
>>> find_top_frequency("foo bar foo foo bar 1 1 1 1 1 1")
3
```

Note that `most_common(1).pop()` is a `Tuple[str, int]` of the word and the count (in this case it'd be `('foo', 3)`, so if you want both of those instead of just the count, all you have to do is remove the `[1]`.

Comment: You didn't call the function.  `word.isalpha` is a function, `word.isalpha()` is the result of calling the function.

Comment: The thing you probably want to put into a function is the entire `word for word in text.split() if word.isalpha()` generator -- there's no point just having a new function that checks if a word contains only letters, because that function already exists (it's `isalpha()`)!

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to split in words, count occurrence of each word and return the max:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def find_top_frequency(text: str) -> int:
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)
    counter = Counter(words)
    return max(counter.values())
    # or return counter.most_common(1) if you want the word too.
```

```
# s = "I would love to make this code better but hope you can help me with it. Thank you helping me out. Hope you can help me."

>>> find_top_frequency(s)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple.

EDIT: I forgot to check the characters at first.

```py
import re

test_string = 'bee movie bee movie bee movie script lelelelele-'

def word_counter(string):

    if re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]+',string) == None:

        words = string.split()
        unique_words = set(words)

        word_count_dict = {word:words.count(word) for word in unique_words}

        return word_count_dict

    else:
        print('There are characters which aren\'t whitespaces or letters in your string.')

print(word_counter(test_string))
```